# How to generate toJson with return type Map<String, String> using Freezed lib in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

I want to generate toJson() method with return type `Map<String, String>`

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried "json_serializable" already?

Comment: How can I use that?

Answer (score 0):

Freezed does not allow you to specify the value type in `toJson`, but you can use [`Map.cast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/Map/cast.html).

```dart
Map<String, String> toStringMap() => toJson().cast();
```